# Convert multi-line text to string

Tags: string, csv, output, python-3.7

I am new to Python so please excuse.
I'm running some code that gives the following output-

```
Michael
John
Jack
Harry
```

I want to convert the output  like

```
'Michael','John',Jack','Harry'
```

How should I go about doing this.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What is the variable that you are going to output? Is it a list?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do you have some code that you've tried out that doesn't work right? Let's see the code, please.

Comment: @White159 Yes, it is a list.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is a string you can convert it to list using `split()`

```
myString = 'Someone, something, somebody'
myList = myString.split(', ')
```

The newly created `myList` will look like this:

```
['Someone', 'something', 'somebody']
```

If you have many strings that you want to add to a list you can use `append()`

```
myList.append(myString)
```

Or you can just add them all together:

```
myList = [myString0, myString1]
```

Comment: I want to convert the string to a list.

Comment: @nightis show the code please to answer you correctly. What are you trying to do? What  do you have in your hand?